# What ports are open by default in most firewalls/how do push notifications work?

Tags: sockets, networking, server, push-notification, client

I'm working on a project with a server and a client that will require the server to be able to send push notifications to the client. I know this can be done, I'm getting push notifications as we speak, but my firewall is set to

"Typical Security (Default): Allows all traffic from home network to internet and blocks all unrelated traffic from internet to home network."

Clearly this is a lie. WAN to LAN traffic has to be allowed in at least some cases in order for push notifications to work. For my project, I'd like to do it the "correct" way. Is there a default port or set of ports thats left open for this kind of thing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: By default, a firewall will block _all_ connections initiated from the outside. Most likely, the host on the inside is creating a connection to the outside in order to receive push notifications on the the connection.

Comment: @RonMaupin Then is it standard practice to ping a server every second or so to keep a connection alive?

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which is connectionless. Different devices and application use different protocols.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry, I don't mean literally ping. I mean send frequent "keep alive" requests to the server to, well, keep the connection alive.

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all answer. Some things may use the automatic TCP keepalives, some may use a connectionless protocol like UDP, and create an application connection. TCP can be configured to have long timeouts, and automatically send keepalives.